# Python pandas rolling_apply two column input into function

Tags: python, pandas

Following on from this question [Python custom function using rolling_apply for pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21025821/python-custom-function-using-rolling-apply-for-pandas), about using `rolling_apply`. Although I have progressed with my function, I am struggling to deal with a function that requires two or more columns as inputs:

Creating the same setup as before

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

tmp  = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2000,2)/10000, 
                    index=pd.date_range('2001-01-01',periods=2000),
                    columns=['A','B'])
```

But changing the function slightly to take two columns.

```
def gm(df,p):
    df = pd.DataFrame(df)
    v =((((df['A']+df['B'])+1).cumprod())-1)*p
    return v.iloc[-1]
```

It produces the following error:

```
pd.rolling_apply(tmp,50,lambda x: gm(x,5))

  KeyError: u'no item named A'
```

I think it is because the input to the lambda function is an ndarray of length 50 and only of the first column, and doesn't take two columns as the input. Is there a way to get both columns as inputs and use it in a `rolling_apply` function.

Again any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486502/why-does-pandas-rolling-use-single-dimension-ndarray/52029402#52029402. See my answer there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas Dataframe rolling with two columns and two rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390467/pandas-dataframe-rolling-with-two-columns-and-two-rows)

Answer (score 15):

Not sure if still relevant here, with the new `rolling` classes on pandas, whenever we pass `raw=False` to `apply`, we are actually passing the series to the wraper, which means we have access to the index of each observation, and can use that to further handle multiple columns.

From the docs:

> **raw** : bool, default None
>
> > False : passes each row or column as a Series to the function.

> > True or None : the passed function will receive ndarray objects instead. If you are just applying a NumPy reduction function this will achieve much better performance.

In this scenario, we can do the following:

```py
### create a func for multiple columns
def cust_func(s):

    val_for_col2 = df.loc[s.index, col2] #.values
    val_for_col3 = df.loc[s.index, col3] #.values
    val_for_col4 = df.loc[s.index, col4] #.values
    
    ## apply over multiple column values
    return np.max(s) *np.min(val_for_col2)*np.max(val_for_col3)*np.mean(val_for_col4)
    

### Apply to the dataframe
df.rolling('10s')['col1'].apply(cust_func, raw=False)
```

Note that here we can still use all functionalities from `pandas rolling` class, which is particularly useful when dealing with time-related windows.

The fact that we are passing one column and using the entire dataframe feels like a hack, but it works in practice.

Comment: works for me, thanks. just note its np.max(val_for_col3), not np.max(val_for_cal3)

Comment: Thanks @GivenX, just fixed it.

Comment: Saves an awful lot of hassle.

Comment: Very neat answer but what does 10s at the last line of the code means?

Comment: @High GPA it means 10 seconds

Answer (score 9):

Looks like rolling_apply will try to convert input of user func into ndarray (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.stats.moments.rolling_apply.html?highlight=rolling_apply#pandas.stats.moments.rolling_apply).

Workaround based on using aux column *ii* which is used to select window inside of manipulating function gm:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

tmp = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2000,2)/10000, columns=['A','B'])
tmp['date'] = pd.date_range('2001-01-01',periods=2000)
tmp['ii'] = range(len(tmp))            

def gm(ii, df, p):
    x_df = df.iloc[map(int, ii)]
    #print x_df
    v =((((x_df['A']+x_df['B'])+1).cumprod())-1)*p
    #print v
    return v.iloc[-1]

#print tmp.head()
res = pd.rolling_apply(tmp.ii, 50, lambda x: gm(x, tmp, 5))
print res
```

Comment: This is slick.  I like it.

Comment: In this spirit, how would you pull off a similar hack if the index were a multi-index?  Or any non-numerical index, for that matter?  Always necessary to first convert the index to floats?

Comment: i modified my answer so it no longer uses indexes. gm still getting array of floats so i have to map them to ints to be used with iloc

Comment: The idea works, but after trying this approach it seems more complicated than it needs to be.  I now just use a for loop to roll through the dataframe and can both evaluate and calculate multiple columns.

Comment: with for loops you may end up with code which is MUCH slower - sometimes it is a big problem.

Comment: @lowtech that's right, but it's also worth to note that many other times a for loop will do it, avoiding a possible case of premature optimization. There seems to be (please, please someone correct me!!) no proper support for doing this in pandas, so using a for loop to solve the problem is not injustified IMO, if performance allows. Optimize later.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another version of this question: [Using rolling_apply on a DataFrame object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19121854/using-rolling-apply-on-a-dataframe-object). Use this if your function returns a Series.

Since yours returns a scalar, do this.

```
In [71]: df  = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2000,2)/10000, 
                    index=pd.date_range('2001-01-01',periods=2000),
                    columns=['A','B'])
```

Redefine your function to return a tuple with the index you want to use and scalar value that is computed. Note that this is slightly different as we are returning the first index here (and not the normally returned last, youy could do either).

```
In [72]: def gm(df,p):
              v =((((df['A']+df['B'])+1).cumprod())-1)*p
              return (df.index[0],v.iloc[-1])


In [73]: Series(dict([ gm(df.iloc[i:min((i+1)+50,len(df)-1)],5) for i in xrange(len(df)-50) ]))

Out[73]: 
2001-01-01    0.000218
2001-01-02   -0.001048
2001-01-03   -0.002128
2001-01-04   -0.003590
2001-01-05   -0.004636
2001-01-06   -0.005377
2001-01-07   -0.004151
2001-01-08   -0.005155
2001-01-09   -0.004019
2001-01-10   -0.004912
2001-01-11   -0.005447
2001-01-12   -0.005258
2001-01-13   -0.004437
2001-01-14   -0.004207
2001-01-15   -0.004073
...
2006-04-20   -0.006612
2006-04-21   -0.006299
2006-04-22   -0.006320
2006-04-23   -0.005690
2006-04-24   -0.004316
2006-04-25   -0.003821
2006-04-26   -0.005102
2006-04-27   -0.004760
2006-04-28   -0.003832
2006-04-29   -0.004123
2006-04-30   -0.004241
2006-05-01   -0.004684
2006-05-02   -0.002993
2006-05-03   -0.003938
2006-05-04   -0.003528
Length: 1950
```

Answer (score 0):

All rolling_* functions works on 1d array. I'm sure one can invent some workarounds for passing 2d arrays, but in your case, you can simply precompute row-wise values for rolling evaluation:

```
>>> def gm(x,p):
...     return ((np.cumprod(x) - 1)*p)[-1]
...
>>> pd.rolling_apply(tmp['A']+tmp['B']+1, 50, lambda x: gm(x,5))
2001-01-01   NaN
2001-01-02   NaN
2001-01-03   NaN
2001-01-04   NaN
2001-01-05   NaN
2001-01-06   NaN
2001-01-07   NaN
2001-01-08   NaN
2001-01-09   NaN
2001-01-10   NaN
2001-01-11   NaN
2001-01-12   NaN
2001-01-13   NaN
2001-01-14   NaN
2001-01-15   NaN
...
2006-06-09   -0.000062
2006-06-10   -0.000128
2006-06-11    0.000185
2006-06-12   -0.000113
2006-06-13   -0.000962
2006-06-14   -0.001248
2006-06-15   -0.001962
2006-06-16   -0.003820
2006-06-17   -0.003412
2006-06-18   -0.002971
2006-06-19   -0.003882
2006-06-20   -0.003546
2006-06-21   -0.002226
2006-06-22   -0.002058
2006-06-23   -0.000553
Freq: D, Length: 2000
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but the example function of `gm` was merely a mock example...so I am still keen to figure out what the work around is to get two or more columns...