# Improve speed of pandas rolling apply

Tags: python, pandas, performance, parallel-processing, apply

I'm trying to improve the runtime speed of pandas rolling apply. My input dataframe is pretty big [df.shape=(257,2000000)] so I'm getting runtimes on the order of a number of days, which is unacceptable.

Here's my function:

```
def rolling_grad(y):
    model = stats.linregress(np.arange(len(y)), y)
    return model[0]
```

That applies over every column in the df:

```
grad = df.rolling(30).apply(rolling_grad)
```

Essentially I'm after the slope in rolling windows of size 30 for each column. I've tried using swifter and pandarallel with no luck.

Any help/advice very much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You should read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25583494/faster-rolling-apply-on-a-pandas-dataframe

Comment: Have you tried using Dask or pyspark?