# Dataframe percentile using a rolling value from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, percentile

I have below dataframe structure as a sample.

I want to obtain a column where it calculates the percentile of the "price column" based on the value of the "percentile" column, using a rolling n period lookback.

Is it possible? I tried using some kind of a lambda function and use the .apply syntax but couldn't get it to work.

```
        date     percentile  price   desired_row
    2019-11-08  0.355556    0.6863    36th percentile of price of last n period
    2019-11-11  0.316667    0.6851    32nd percentile of price of last n period
    2019-11-12  0.305556    0.6841    ...
    2019-11-13  0.302778    0.6838    ...
    2019-11-14  0.244444    0.6798    ...
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52029516/9274732), you can use `rolling` on the column price with the column percentile in index and then use [`quantile`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.quantile.html) in `apply` with the parameter `raw=False`:

```
window = 3
df['desired_row'] = df.set_index('percentile')['price'].rolling(window)\
                      .apply(lambda x: x.quantile(q=x.index[-1]), raw=False).values
print (df)
         date  percentile   price  desired_row
0  2019-11-08    0.355556  0.6863          NaN
1  2019-11-11    0.316667  0.6851          NaN
2  2019-11-12    0.305556  0.6841     0.684711
3  2019-11-13    0.302778  0.6838     0.683982
4  2019-11-14    0.244444  0.6798     0.681756
```

you can change the `interpolation` parameter in `quantile` depending on your need.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rolling method in pandas. For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B': [0, 1, 2, 2, 4]})
df['rolling_mean'] = df['B'].rolling(2).mean()
```

will create a new column of the two period rolling average of the 'B' column. You can apply different methods if you need to compute a different summary statistic, for example:

```
df['rolling_sum'] = df['B'].rolling(2).sum()
```

See for more on the functionality:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html