# rolling apply return dict

Tags: pandas, dataframe, apply, window-functions

I have a custom function which returns a `dict` and stores it to every cell to every row:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})


def custom_rolling_apply(arr):
    return {'sum': np.sum(arr), 'mean': np.mean(arr)}

df['rolling_dict'] = np.NaN
df['rolling_dict'] = df['rolling_dict'].astype('object')
df['rolling_dict'] = df['A'].rolling(window=3).apply(custom_rolling_apply, raw=True)
```

Why does this say:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not dict
```

`pandas` version : 1.5.3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas apply on rolling with multi-column output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62716558/pandas-apply-on-rolling-with-multi-column-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`rolling.aggregate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.aggregate.html#pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.aggregate) instead of `apply`;

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})


df['rolling_dict'] = np.NaN
df['rolling_dict'] = df['rolling_dict'].astype('object')
df['A'].rolling(window=3).aggregate({'sum': np.sum, 'mean': np.mean}, raw=True)
```

Output

```
    sum  mean
0   NaN  NaN
1   NaN  NaN
2   6.0  2.0
3   9.0  3.0
4   12.0 4.0
```

From the `rolling.apply` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html):

> func function Must produce a single value from an `ndarray` input if
> `raw=True` or a single value from a `Series` if `raw=False`. Can also accept
> a Numba JIT function with `engine='numba'` specified

Note that `apply` carries a performance penalty if your data is large:

```
import numpy as np
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


def custom_rolling_apply(arr):
    q={'sum':np.sum(arr), 'mean': np.mean(arr)}
    return q

def rolling_with_aggregate(arr):
    q=arr.rolling(window=3).aggregate({'sum': np.sum, 'mean': np.mean}, raw=True)
    return q

def profile_rolling_operation(data_size):
    rolling_times_1 = []
    rolling_times_2 = []
    data_sizes = []
    for i in range(1, data_size + 1):
        data_sizes.append(i)
        df = pd.DataFrame({'A': np.random.randint(1, 10, i)})
        elapsed_time_1 = timeit.timeit(lambda: [custom_rolling_apply(arr) for arr in df['A'].rolling(window=3)], number=2)
        rolling_times_1.append(elapsed_time_1)
        elapsed_time_2 = timeit.timeit(lambda: rolling_with_aggregate(df['A']), number=2)
        rolling_times_2.append(elapsed_time_2)
    return data_sizes, rolling_times_1, rolling_times_2

max_data_size = 1000
data_sizes, rolling_times_1, rolling_times_2 = profile_rolling_operation(max_data_size)

plt.plot(data_sizes, rolling_times_1, label='Custom Rolling Apply')
plt.plot(data_sizes, rolling_times_2, label='Rolling with Aggregate')
plt.xlabel('Data Size')
plt.ylabel('Execution Time (seconds)')
plt.title('Comparison')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, rolling apply must produce a single value: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.apply.html

Therefore, we will iterate through the rolling windows to get to the same point:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})


def custom_rolling_apply(arr):
    q = {'sum': np.sum(arr), 'mean': np.mean(arr)}
    return q

df['rolling_dict'] = [custom_rolling_apply(i) for i in df['A'].rolling(window=3)]
print(df)
```